# iPod headphone to USB adapter

Tags: usb, ipod, headphones

I have a set of [headphones](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001V9LPT4) that have controls specifically designed for the iPhone, that is, they send signals through the 3.5mm cable and they are interpreted by the iPhone. I would like to connect them to my laptop and continue to use their controls. Does such an adapter exist? If not, I will make a new post on electronics.SE about building such a device.

Comment: Regarding that last bit, editing it out and asking for instructions instead of opinion on [Electronics.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) might be the way to go.

Comment: Good point. I'll remove it and make a new post if I don't get an answer to this one in a week.